# SFTP file manipulation using shell script

Tags: shell, sftp

Has anyone tried to access and manipulate files in an SFTP server using shell script Basically, here's what I have to do:
1. Open SFTP, access the designated directory
2. Loop through all .txt files
3. Read filename of each .txt files and only get the file/s that contain/s 'XX' substring
     (i.e. hello-XX.txt)
4. Rename that file by appending an '-OK' string
     (i.e.hello-XX-OK.txt)

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Instead of the shell, use some scripting language (Perl, Python, Ruby, etc.) and a suitable module.

Comment: Hi Salva, I'm using shell as I need to implement this in SAP PI which is running in unix.

Comment: If you can run shell scripts you can run any other script. Any Unix system deployed in the current millennium has, at least, Perl available as part of the base OS install.

Comment: @MarkBernabe - Did you make much progress on this? I'm just starting out with automating `sftp` (via `sshpass`) from a BASH script and your question pops up first yet without very satisfying answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) is for. Roughly:

```
#!/PATH/TO/expect -f
spawn sftp host
expect -re "Username:"
send -- "MYUSER\r"
expect -re "Password:"
send -- "PASSWORD\r"
expect -re "ftp>"
send -- "cd mydir\r"
expect -re "ftp>"
send -- "get myfile\r"
...
```

Comment: A shebang (`#!` line) typically only accepts one argument to the specified command; `#!/usr/bin/env expect -f` likely won't work. If `expect` is in `/usr/bin`, just use `#!/usr/bin/expect -f`. See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) and [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454) for discussion of the "env hack".

Comment: Thanks - tried to be too smart (this always works in python).

Answer (score 0):

You can script SFTP with a "here document" (`<<EOF`, as specified [here](http://www.snailbook.com/faq/scripting-sftp.auto.html)), but you won't be able to use shell-script-like primitives (a la bash) in an SFTP script.

Perhaps try an SSH-based script instead, if you have SSH access.

Comment: Hi Christian, any SSH-based script sample?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your description requires you to run any logic on the sftp server. You can just get the data using the sftp command and do the processing locally, e.g.:

```
for file in $(echo 'ls -1' | sftp blah | tail -n +2); do
  # do stuff
done
```

Comment: Hi Vanza, can you elaborate more on how I can loop thru specific directory in the SFTP server?

Comment: @MarkBernabe: I just did, read the code I posted. It loops through the files in the home directory on the sftp server. Modify it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use Perl for that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
$sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, user => $user, autodie => 1);
$sftp->setcwd($dir);
$sftp->mget("*XX*.txt", $local_dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point that I got working for my own purposes. I'm using `sshpass` so that the password can be specified but you should be able to remove that extra goo if you have the RSA public keys properly exchanged.

```
#!/bin/bash

function sftpexec()
{
    (SSHPASS="password" sshpass -e sftp user@server | tail -n +2) << !
$1
!
}

FILES=$(sftpexec ls)
echo $FILES
```

What this will do is list all the files on the server in the starting directory.