# How can I handel errors in .ksh file

Tags: unix, ftp

I am writing a ksh file which will create FTP a file to the ftp location ..

```
cd ${RUNTIME}
NOW=$(date +"%y%m%d%H%M%S")
ftp -i -n -v ${TEST_TP_SERVER} <<END
user $TEST_TP_USER_ID $TEST_TP_USER_PWD
lcd ${OUTDIR}
put "TEST.txt" "$NOW.ABC"
quit
END
```

My question is how can I handel errors here in this file .
If something happens after cd ${RUNTIME} line then I can write like this  :

```
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then 
  echo "Can not connect , wrong user name / password " 
  exit 1 
fi
```

But after  `ftp -i -n -v ${TEST_TP_SERVER} <<END` line I cant write the same .
So can anyone please tell me how can I write error handling part after FTP command ?

Answer (score 0):

Using explicit input to the `ftp` command is inherently unreliable from the error checking point of view. Find one of the dozens questions on Stack Overflow showing how to automate FTP sessions using `expect` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531699/sftp-file-manipulation-using-shell-script) is one) and use something similar. That way, you can reliably detect and handle errors as well as deal with timeouts and disconnects.